# removing lines between two tokens in java file using ant

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to make a copy of my java file in src by deleting all lines between two tokens. 
ex:

```
//[start]
   if(true){
      ....
   }
//[END] 

 ....

//[START]
  if(true){
  ....
  }
 //[END]
```

so i am able to create a copy and replace the tokens with something else like this by using **copy** and **filterset** and **filter** tag in build.xml

```
/*
  if(true){
  ....
  }
 */


 /*
  if(true){
  ....
  }
 */
```

but this fails when there is a nested loop inside, so i want a way to **delete** all the lines between the tokens **//[START]** and **//[END]**.

Please help as i am new to ant.

Comment: ANT is not a programming language. Consider using a template based code generator. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361168/java-using-ant-to-automatically-generate-boilerplate-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this tag by replacing the START & END with required tokens and it worked.

```
 <replaceregexp byline="false" flags="gs" match ="//START(.*?)//END" replace =" " />
```